# Firebase between different IOS Apps NSKeyedUnarchiver terminating

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a Project which contains a Mobile IOS App and a separate iPad App. These communicate with Firebase Database.

On the mobile app it works perfectly to archiver objects and unarchiver it on another mobile device, but on the iPad it I get the following error and a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It always terminates in the following line:

```
let ar = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: array) as! [ProjectModel]
```

The value array is Data of type Data.

The Object-File:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ProjectModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

var name: String!
var controllerArray: [ControllerModel]!

init(name: String!, controllerArray: [ControllerModel]!) {

    self.name = name
    self.controllerArray = controllerArray

}

required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    let controllerArray = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "controllerArray") as! [ControllerModel]
    self.init(name: name, controllerArray: controllerArray)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(controllerArray, forKey: "controllerArray")
}
```

}

Comment: Please add firebase database screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the Problem. You need to use the Class Codable instead of NSKeyedUnarchiver.

Here a link to a blog post which helps me: [medium.com/codable](https://medium.com/commencis/swift-4s-codable-one-last-battle-for-serialization-30ceb3ccb051)